# How can I catch Vue Warn '[Vue warn]: Missing required prop'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a component set like:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    prop1: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  }
}
```

If I don't provide the required `prop1`, Vue emits a warning like

```
[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "prop1"
```

I'm wondering, how can I catch this warn and do something about it?

---

My use case is using the component as a page, with `props: true` on the VueRouter.

If it's a navigation inside my application using `$router.push({params: {prop1: 'whatever' }})`, everything works well.

But if the user lands on the url, the props won't be set and I want to display a message or redirect him or whatever.

---

I know I can make the props not required and validate it on the `mounted`, but it seems duplicating code.

I'm imagining something like `Component.mountedError()`

Comment: The `required` flag and prop `validator()` are intended for development only, so they're not included in the production/minified build, and you wouldn't be able to catch any errors from them. The behavior you're seeking indeed requires custom validation in `mounted()`.

Answer (score 2):

you could work around the `validator` method by adding a default value
and check if the props still have this default value throw a custom error
and return with `true` to disallow `Vue` to throw its own warning like this

```js
Vue.component('alert', {
  template: `
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1> 
  `,
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: 'default',
      validator: function(value) {
        if (value === 'default') {
          console.log('Custom error message here')
          alert('props required');
        }
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
})



let vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <alert />
</div>
```